# Resize VirtualBox Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning

Need to resize Ubuntu partition under VirtualBox. As per other posts, have resized VirtualBox from 8GB to 16GB. Have booted Ubuntu 16.04.1 from DVD.

I started gparted and see four partitions:

/dev/sda1 [ext4] which is 7.5GB [this is the partition I want to enlarge],

/dev/sda2 [extended] which is 510MB,

/dev/sda5 [linux-swap] which is 510MB,

followed by unallocated 8GB.

Unfortunately, selecting the sda1 partition and attempting Resize/Move shows no chance to enlarge. Selecting the sda2 partition and attempting Resize/Move does show the ability to consume the unallocated space, but this is not the partition I want to enlarge. Ditto swap.

How to get gparted to enlarge the sda1 partition? Thanks.
[GParted screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZjJS.jpg)

Comment: It sounds like you will have to move the other partition(s) to free up the space.  Be sure to back up completely before performing any partition operations.

Comment: Yes, moving sda2 and sda5 then enlarging sda1 seemed the right thing to do. sda2 shows zero free space before and 8GB after. I tried setting 8GB free before and zero free space after, but gparted then increased the sda2 partition size from 510MB to 8GB, which is not what I want.

Comment: Looking at another post, I perform a "sudo fdisk -l" and found that sda2 [ext4] and sda5 [linux-swap] occupy the same space on the hard drive, i.e., sda2 is a container for sda5. It appears sda2 and sda5 have to be resized and/or moved together. Can anyone detail the gparted sequence to do that, ultimately resulting in sda1 become the sole enlarged partition?

Comment: If you edit your question to include a current-window-only screenshot of gparted, I can make better recommendations. Please start new comments directed at me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Uploaded screenshot of gparted, taken from Ubuntu 16.04.1 booted from DVD. Note that, according to fdisk, sda2 and sda5 appear to occupy the same space on the hard drive. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I've completed my answer, below.

Comment: @heynnema I think what I need to do is: (1) enlarge sda2 to the maximum of 8703MB, thus consuming all the unallocated space, (2) maybe do the same for sda5, maybe not, (3) contract sda2 back to 511MB, with a free space preceding of 8193MB [this may cause problems if sda5 was also enlarged], (4) enlarge sda1 to consume the unallocated space, now between sda1 and sda2. But I'd someone in the know to confirm this before undertaking it.

Comment: I'll give your answer a try, and confirm results, thanks.

Comment: @heynnema Bad news. After swapoff, and move/resize sda2, I see precede of 0, size of 511MB, following of 8193, align MiB. When I change following to 0, then press TAB, following does become 0, but size automatically changes to 8703, and the horizontal bar hasn't moved. I believe I have hit your STOP NOW. What next? Perhaps manually set size to 511 and precede to 8193? Perhaps the swap space sda5 contained in sda2 is causing trouble?

Comment: Yes, I thought that might happen. That's why I put in the stop here. Because sda2 is an extended partition, it makes it difficult to use graphic tools to move/resize it. Restart that step, and change the `space before` to 8193, see if the partition size stays at 511, and the `space after` goes to zero. If not, manually change all three values so that it's 8193/511/0 (the partition size needs to be 511) (the last value may be a 1 and that's ok too). Report back, and I'll update my answer with what you finally do.

Comment: @heynnema No dice. Cancelled the first attempted change, re-entered move/resize, tried to set preceding to 8193, on hitting TAB gparted resets the field to zero. Then set following to zero, on hitting TAB gparted sets size to 8703. If I then set preceding to 8193, on TAB gparted resets preceding to zero. If I then set size to 511, on TAB gparted sets following to 8192. Gparted is apparently unwilling to permit preceding to be a non-zero number, perhaps because gparted is worrying about sda5?

Comment: Yeah, sometimes at acts funny, and makes you jump through hoops to get it right. Try using a before of 8190 and and after of 1... so 8190/511/1... the only value that's important is the 511. If that doesn't work... we'll do it the longer way around, but guaranteed to work. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema Sorry, gparted simply will not let me leave any non-zero value in preceding. Whatever I plug into size gets reflected in following, and vice versa. But any non-zero value in preceding gets reset to zero as soon as I leave the field. Ready for the "longer way", thanks.

Comment: OK, give me a few minutes to re-edit my answer.

Comment: @heynnema I see your updated answer. Proceeding, will advise, thanks.

Comment: @heynnema Ah, see you're still editing, will wait...

Comment: I'm done. Have at it. Report back. Add new comments under my answer.

Comment: @heynnema All OK up to create swap partition. On OK, the gparted main pane shows "New Partition #1" not /dev/sda2. Deleted that swap partition, retried New partition, doesn't seem to be any way for me to specify the partition name. Have done everything else in step #2. Swap is 512MB and located at high end of hard disk. /dev/sda1 is 15.5GB and located at low end of hard disk. But partition name for swap is "New Partition #1". Shall I apply the changes? [Note that swap partition is type "linux-swap" not simply "swap" but that was the only swap option available.]

Comment: Go ahead. Quite a bit of work, huh? Reply in comments under my answer, 'cause their gonna make us move to chat if we continue here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We'll be **deleting** sda2/sda5, **recreating** a new sda2 swap partition and **moving** it to the right. Then we'll **resize** sda1.

## Backup any important data on sda1 (standard disclaimer)

## Step #1

- boot your Ubuntu VM
- first we'll disable the current swap...
- open a `terminal` and type:

  - `sudo swapoff -a`
  - `gksudo gedit /etc/fstab`
  - find the line with `swap` that looks similar to `UUID=071f8b0e-8e16-4f4d-90ff-a4ae9cc56e2b  none  swap  sw  0  0`, and place a `#` at the beginning of the line to disable it
  - save and quit gedit
- we'll come back later and re-edit /etc/fstab

## Step #2

- boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD in your VM
- start `gparted`
- in the lower pane, right-click on sda5 and issue a **swapoff** command
- in the lower pane, right-click on sda5 and issue a **delete** command
- in the lower pane, right-click on sda2 and issue a **delete** command
- in the lower pane, right-click on the unallocated space and create a new swap partition, file system type = `linux-swap`, size approximately = `512-1024MB`. Note what partition number gets created... probably sda2
- in the lower pane, right-click on sda2 and issue a **move**/resize command
- in the upper pane, hover the mouse pointer over the new swap partition, it'll change to a hand cursor, click/hold and **move** it all the way to the right
- in the lower pane, right-click on sda1 and issue at move/**resize** command
- in the graphic portion of the move/**resize** window, hover the mouse pointer over the right side of sda1 and note the arrow. **Resize** sda1 by dragging the right side all the way to the right. Click OK.
- observe the graphic and confirm that it's right... two partitions... sda1 and sda2 swap... if not... then **STOP HERE!**
- Click the Apply icon

## Step #3

- boot back into Ubuntu VM
- open a `terminal` and type:

  - `sudo mkswap /dev/sda2` # changing sda2 to the value noted above, if need be
  - **copy** the new UUID that is displayed to the clipboard
  - if no new UUID is displayed, type `sudo blkid` and note the new UUID there
  - `gksudo gedit /etc/fstab`
  - remove the `#` from the beginning of the swap line
  - replace the UUID value with a **paste** of the new UUID from the clipboard
  - save and quit gedit
  - type `sudo swapon -a`
- you're done
- reboot your VM

Comment: It worked. You did it. Is there any way I can substantively express my gratitude for your time?

Comment: @FrankNatoli Great! Did the swap finally show up as sda2 after you hit apply? In terminal, type `swapon` and `free -h` and confirm that swap is fully working. If you can vote, can you click the up arrow that's over the 0, just to the left of my answer?

Comment: Yes, swap became /dev/sda2. No, I am a peasant who cannot vote! I clicked the check, that's the best I can do.